# Azure Cognitive Services for different clients, can use one model?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have multiple Azure Congnitive Services (resources), one per client, to see the statistics. Can I use the same model, for my multiple Azure Cognitives Services?

Comment: If they are the same type of Cognitive Services, like for instance all of them are text analytics, then yes.

Comment: API Type: Form Recognizer. I have error, no model found. Something like this..

Comment: You're going to have to give us some more information if you want us to be able to help you. Please provide a [MCVE] and refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. It depends on the requirements from each client. If the model solves the common problem for all of those clients and give the desired result with same type of cognitive service.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Microsoft. You cannot use a model from a Resource in another Resource. But you can copy the model from one resource to another with:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/samples/Sample7_CopyCustomModel.md